# Cocoa touch - Error getting JSON key

Tags: json, cocoa-touch, ios6

So I am parsing the www.twitch.tv API json page.

Here is the link: (these 2 people are normally always streaming - if the json data shows as [] it means they are offline.  if someone is offline, json has no data)
http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=vokemodels
http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=mathmind

My problem is that in my iOS application, I can do:

```
[dictionary objectForKey:@"stream_count"]];
```

And I do **successfully** get data from the JSON and it **will** log correctly.  However, when trying to get data from the "screen_cap_url_medium" key, I do the following code:

```
[dictionary objectForKey:@"screen_cap_url_medium"]];
```

And I get a `(null)` when logging.  I am **absolutely positive** I am retrieving the JSON data, and I do not have any typos.

When I `NSLog` the entire JSON array from one of the above links, the `"screen_cap_url_medium"` is one of the only keys that are in quotes.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect your json you'll see that `screen_cap_url_medium` is under `channel` object, so you can access it like this:

```
[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"channel.screen_cap_url_medium"];
```

PS. Here `dictionary` is obviously the first object of the root array you get back from your response.